# Trying to find some function like setFieldError on Antdesign Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

So I'm trying to manually set a field to error or warning state after the form submitted
but I cant see any function like `setFieldError` on the form hook. As shown on the image i want to set error/warning state to the email field if the user is registered already
[image]

Comment: Paste the code, not the screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state to conditionally appending the customize validation props on the `<Form.Item>`:

```
const [emailExist, setEmailExist] = useState(false);

const emailInputErrorProps = {
    validateStatus: "error",
    help: "Email already exist"
};

<Form
    layout="vertical"
    onValuesChange={handleValuesChange}
    onFinish={handleFinish}
>
    <Form.Item
        name="email"
        label="Email"
        {...(emailExist ? emailInputErrorProps : {})}
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your email!" }]}
    >
        <Input />
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Then on form submit, just set email exist to true:

```
const handleFinish = async (values) => {
    //email exist after checking from server
    const emailProblem = true;
    if (emailProblem) {
        setEmailExist(true);
    } else {
        //register the user
    }
};
```

[image]

see full working demo/code below (includes handleValuesChange):

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]